# what is the smallest unit of a real number to which it is composed of?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I searched for relevant questions but my point is different. For example take set of real numbers with usual order then is the immediate successor of one. Firstly, I ask that is there any such number?? If yes then how surprisingly we beleive existence of a number but we cannot see that???

Comment: There is no such number

Comment: There is no gap. It is the fact that there is no gap which implies that there is no unique "next" number. If there were a "next" number, there would be empty space between $x$ and the next number after $x.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers have shown, the real numbers are *dense* - between any two, there is a third, so that there is never a "next real number".

You write in response to this:

> then there must be a gap on the real line

and I think this is really the "meat" of the question.

Actually, the situation here is the opposite - if there *were* real numbers $a<b$ with no real in between them, *that would be a hole*! There'd be a "gap" between $a$ and $b$, where there should be a real but there isn't.

In fact, in a precise sense, the reals have no "holes" - see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) for example, or better yet [Dedekind's essay on constructing the reals from the rationals by "filling in" the holes](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21016). There are multiple ways to describe the "fullness" of the reals; the two most common ones are:

- the [least upper bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property): any nonempty set of reals with an upper bound has a least upper bound

and

- the [completeness property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space): every [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) converges.

---

I think what's confusing you is the following: we can define what "next real number" means, and yet they don't exist! So doesn't this represent a "gap" in the reals, in the sense that some possible behavior doesn't occur?

*Note: If that's not what you mean by "gap", then what **do** you mean?*

Well, the problem is this: *just because you can describe something, doesn't mean it should exist*. For instance, I can also imagine real numbers for which multiplication isn't [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property): that is, reals $r, s$ with $r\cdot s\not=s\cdot r$. Yet multiplication of reals *is* commutative! There are no such reals $r$ and $s$. And in fact, this is a property we *want $\mathbb{R}$ to have*, similarly to how the [field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) - which imply that there are no successive real numbers - are properties we want $\mathbb{R}$ to have.

If you don't find this satisfying - and I suspect you won't at first - try making precise what you mean by "gap." I think in your efforts to do so, you'll see what I'm getting at.

Comment: There is no real number immidiately next to a real number? Perhaps there is some number we cannot discover yet

Comment: @MuhammadTahir It's not that we haven't discovered all the reals - we can *prove* that between any two reals, there is a third. Namely, if $a<b$, then ${a+b}\over 2$ is between $a$ and $b$. So it's not that we haven't *found* the "next real", it's that it *doesn't exist*. Do you understand why this is true?

Answer (score 1):

There is always a real number between an two distinct real numbers $a$ and $b$. For example $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: so whats the conclusion?

Comment: there is no such thing as an immediate successor.

Comment: then what is 'next' to one? a number or a hole?

Comment: neither, it does not exist, there is no such thing as the next one. The same thing happens with water after it stops becoming drops.

Comment: nor a number nor a hole then whats the possibility?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Another possibility is that the concept "next to" does not make sense for real numbers.

Comment: set or real numbers is linearly ordered by less than

Comment: @MuhammadTahir But this does not give us the concept of "а real number next to а real number". How would you define a number next to a number $x$?

Comment: I cannot define this thats why i asked for any idea

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a number. Arguing by way of contradiction, for given $r\in\mathbb{R}$, suppose that $r_0$ is immediate successor of $r$. Then, $r<\frac{r+r_0}{2}< r_0$; a contradiction.

Comment: then there is hole?